Can I use the aws bedrock api as a sts assumed role?
I was allocated as a sts assumed-role under the institution. My Arn is ""Arn": "arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/xx-xx-xx/xx@xx.com"". And I was not given with any sessionName or api key. Can I use bedrock API services in the local python boto3 environment with API? Many thanks!
I tried search the solution to access the api. There are only some post about IAM user but not for sts assumed-role.

If the assume role has permissions for Bedrock, then you can access
